# How do you get the duration of a video captured via PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I need to know the duration of a video captured via PhoneGap before uploading to the server. The documentation for the [MediaFile.getFormatData](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile.getFormatData) is a little vague and doesn't seem to be working.

I have been able to successfully capture and upload a video, so all of that is working, just the duration part isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Running on an iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.1

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFile) {
        if(mediaFiles.length == 1) {
            $('#video_url').val(mediaFiles[0]);
            var profileVideo = document.getElementById('profile-video');
            profileVideo.src = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;

            var formatData;
            mediaFiles[0].getFormatData(function(data) {
                formatData = data;
            });

            if(formatData.duration > 30) {
                $('#infoMessage').html("Your video is longer than the allowed 30 seconds. Please record a new video. You can trim your video after it's been recorded.")
            }
        }
    }, function(error) {
    }, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call async code in an synchronous manner. Try it like this instead:

```
mediaFiles[0].getFormatData(function(data) {
    if(data.duration > 30) {
        $('#infoMessage').html("Your video is longer than the allowed 30 seconds. Please record a new video. You can trim your video after it's been recorded.")
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Simon...I tried your code and it still didn't work :( I put an alert just before the if(data.duration > 30) to show the data.duration value and the alert never comes up.

Comment: That should work but one thing I just notice in your original example is that you pass in "mediaFile" but refer to it as "mediaFiles" everywhere else. This typo may be causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll take a look...been a LONG week getting ready for an App Store launch :D

Comment: Stupid spelling mistakes :s  Thanks again Simon!!

Comment: hi @SimonMacDonald hi in android 4.2.2 (nexus 4) data.duration always return 0 why ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles) {
            mediaFiles[0].getFormatData(function(data) {
                if(data.duration > 30) {
                    alert('Your video is longer than the allowed 30 seconds.');
                }
            });
    }, function(error) { alert('An error occured'); }, null);
```

Comment: Sorry guys. I don't saw that mine answer seems like the Simon's.