# Cordova: How to restrict user to upload only 15 sec video?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, video, cordova-plugins

I'm using `Cordova` media capture `plugin` for uploading video but I'm not able to get the duration of that video, so that is why I'm not able to understand how can I restrict user to upload only 15 sec video.

I also tried this method: [How do you get the duration of a video captured via PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512513/how-do-you-get-the-duration-of-a-video-captured-via-phonegap) to stop the user to upload more than 15 sec video

It is not working. I'm getting duration 0 in response. Can anyone please help me out to stop user to upload video more than 15 sec.As I read somewhere duration is not anymore supported in this plugin.

Then, how can I allow user to upload only 15 sec video like instagram?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cordova-media-capture [duration option](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/#properties-3):

```
var options = { limit: 1, duration: 15 };
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureVideoWin, captureVideoFail, options);
```

Comment: I tried this method on different devices .It is working well in android kitkat and android jelly bean but it is not working well in lollipop .i passed the duration 15 sec it is not automatically saving the video after 15 sec...

Comment: but i tested on Mircomax spark canvas , Android 5.0.0 .. it is not working as i already passed duration on it.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Cordova Plugin Media Capture docs:

> **Android Quirks**
>
> - The duration parameter is not supported. Recording lengths can't be    limited programmatically.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

I would suggest wrapping your Capture call in a timeout that kills it after 15 seconds.